# Dependent Combo boxes

Tags: sql, filter, combobox, ms-access-2013, cascade

i would like some help understanding how to link two comboboxes together and ultimately find a record. i will simplify my issue. but can give more detail if needed.

I have 2 tables one has districts. the other table has order numbers.

i want to create a 2 combo-boxes that filter to a record. i cant get my district combo box to show only the corresponding order numbers that have the same district. i have tried referencing the first combo-box (forms!form1!disCombo) inside of my second combo-boxes criteria and setting a re-query in the first combo-box but i get a blank list.

So with the crude example i have when i choose district 3 in my first combobox and requery, the second combobox should have only orders 151 and 167

TableDis -----|------TableOrd

---

Districts -----|--------# -|Districts

---

District 1 ------------151 District 3

District 2 ------------101 District 4

District 3 ----------- 167 District 3

District  4 ----------- 181 District 1

Comment: provide code you've used and perhaps your query too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your solution is correct and should work.  From what you have written, are your comboboxes on a subform?  If so, you may just need to rewrite the reference in your second combobox to allow for this - 
[Forms]![ParentFormName]![SubFormName].[Form]![ControlName]

Comment: It is not on a subform. All of the research ive done suggest that my method is valid if i have it requery to update the second box but doesnt seem to work i will look into it

Comment: SELECT SearchQuery12.[Order Number], 
         SearchQuery12.District
         FROM SearchQuery12
          WHERE (((SearchQuery12.District)=[Forms]!
            [TestFormWithDeficiency2]![DisCombo]));

Comment: aboves my sql statement but my second combobox is just blank

Comment: What’s the bound column on your second combo? Is it the district name, or is it an ID? If it’s an ID, set your combo query to look at the district name field itself, rather than the first combobox. That way the first combox updates your form data, so the underlying district name updates based on the selection. The requery of combo 2 runs and the query looks at tge underlying district name and updates as you then expect. That’s assuming your form is based on the two tables and the district name field is part of your form data.